# Swift: Enabling homekit in Xcode, getting error on "Add the home kit feature to your app ID"

Tags: ios, xcode, homekit

Just trying to enable HomeKit in my swift 3 application, and It's giving me this error. Can anyone help?

This is the error I'm getting
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGWFH.jpg

I don't know why this automated process is failing, but does anyone else?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to turn it 'off' and 'on' again. Make sure you have a good internet connection, after that press on the 'fix issue' button.
2. If problem wasn't solved go to the https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle/edit, find 'App IDs' in 'Identifiers' section, choose app id that you use for this application, choose 'edit' and put a checkmark around the HomeKit, it should help.
3. Restart Xcode, clean the project.

Comment: Actually what my problem was, was Xcode had the wrong signing team selected, it has my name, and then my name with (personal team) added to it. It was just my name selected and I had to select the other one